# How to add an author name or copyright symbol on each page in memoir class?

Tags: header-footer, memoir, copyright

I am using the `memoir` document class to write my first book in calculus. How I can display my name, for example, on each page?

Comment: If Werner's answer solved your problem, please accept it by clicking the checkmark to the left, thereby marking the question as "solved", and awarding some points to both Werner and yourself.

Answer (score 11):

The [`memoir` document class](http://ctan.org/pkg/memoir) provides a means to typeset your own headers and footers using a combination of

```
\makepagestyle{<style>}
  \makeevenhead{<style>}{<left>}{<center>}{<right>}% Even page header
  \makeoddhead{<style>}{<left>}{<center>}{<right>}% Odd page header
  \makeevenfoot{<style>}{<left>}{<center>}{<right>}% Even page footer
  \makeoddfoot{<style>}{<left>}{<center>}{<right>}% Odd page footer
```

In the above, you define the style `<style>`. Consequently, if you want to typeset the author name (and a copyright symbol) in the outer footer, with the page number still in the footer centre, you could use

```
\documentclass{memoir}% http://ctan.org/pkg/memoir
...
\makepagestyle{mystyle}% Define 'mystyle' page style
  \makeevenfoot{mystyle}{\textcopyright\ Author name}{\thepage}{}% Even page footer
  \makeoddfoot{mystyle}{}{\thepage}{\textcopyright\ Author name}% Odd page footer
\pagestyle{mystyle}% Set page style to 'mystyle'
\begin{document}
...
\end{document}
```

[image: Own footer style in memoir document class]

The copyright symbol in LaTeX is obtained via `\copyright` or `\textcopyright`. Of course, you can modify the design of both the header and footer to your liking.