# How to modify Memoir class' headers/footers without redefining everything

Tags: header-footer, memoir, parts

I am using the `memoir` class for a multi-part (and multi-book) document. The class' headers and footers suit me fine for a `twoside`, `openright` document, but I'd like to add to them the following:

- In the header, the book and part numbers before the chapter.
- In the footer, a copyright notice.

I've tried to redefine the style, based on [How to add an author name or copyright symbol on each page in memoir class?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/27325/how-to-add-an-author-name-or-copyright-symbol-on-each-page-in-memoir-class), but have been unsuccessful. Is there a way to merely add the above elements to headers/footers without breaking anything else?

Comment: I found this link useful: http://hstuart.dk/2007/06/12/styling-the-page-footer-and-header/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

With the exception of, e.g., part title pages and chapter starting pages, `memoir` by default uses the `headings` pagestyle. The style definition can be found in section 7.3 of the manual; use `\makeevenhead` & friends to change it. The command syntax is `\make<even/odd><head/foot>{<style>}{<left>}{<center>}{<right}`.

EDIT: I also included a new `plainnotice` style (derived from `plain`) that is used for chapter starting pages. Part title pages will still use the `plain` style.

EDIT 2: For "special" chapters like the bibliography one may define a special pagestyle like `headingsnobook` (e.g., resembling the original `headings` style)  and switch to it via `\pagestyle{headingsnobook}`. (The starting pages of "special" chapters will still use `plainnotice`.)

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\makeevenhead{headings}%
    {\thepage}{}{\slshape\bookname~\thebook\qquad\partname~\thepart\qquad\leftmark}
\makeoddhead{headings}{\slshape\rightmark}{}{\thepage}
\makeevenfoot{headings}{}{}{(Copyright notice)}
\makeoddfoot{headings}{(Copyright notice)}{}{}

\copypagestyle{plainnotice}{plain}
\makeevenfoot{plainnotice}{\thepage}{}{(Copyright notice)}% not used with "openright"
\makeoddfoot{plainnotice}{(Copyright notice)}{}{\thepage}
\aliaspagestyle{chapter}{plainnotice}

\copypagestyle{headingsnobook}{headings}
\makeevenhead{headingsnobook}{\thepage}{}{\slshape\leftmark}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\book{The first book}

\part{First}

\chapter{First-first}

\section{First-first-first}

\lipsum[1-10]

\part*{Backmatter}
\pagestyle{headingsnobook}

\begin{thebibliography}{9}
\bibitem{test}\lipsum[1-10]
\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This is almost perfect. How, then, do I avoid having "book" and "part" appear in ToC, LoF, LoT, Glossary and Index sections? Does the solution involve, e.g., adding things like `\createplainmark{glossary}{both}{\glossaryname}`?

Comment: @OlivierDrolet Answer updated.

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you so much. I'm curious, what is the purpose of the second \copypagestyle{headingsnobook}{headings}? It seems to do nothing.

Comment: @OlivierDrolet Indeed. I remove the first one.